# avoid onclick event while scroll box is scrolling firemonkey

Tags: c++, firemonkey, c++builder

I've having a little trouble that I hope you all can help me or orient me, I have a **TVertScrollBox**, it control held many **TRectangle** components, each has assing an **OnClickEvent** that execute some logic, but, when the scroll is scrolling and the user stop it on an **TRectangle** its event **OnClick** is fired, I would like avoid it, but I cannot solve this problem.

I've created an simple code example to show you the problem.

1-Create new Multi-Device Application(C++)
2-Drop on the form an TVertScrollBox from the tool palette.
3-Align to client the TVertScrollBox.

in User declarations Add

```
__fastcall ~TForm1(); // destructor
void __fastcall RectLogicClick(TObject *Sender); // event for OnClickEvent in the TRectangles
TRectangle* rects[20]; // array of rectangles for delete at the end.
```

in FormCreate

```
void __fastcall TForm1::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{
  for(int i=0; i<20; ++i)
  {
    TRectangle * rect = new TRectangle(VertScrollBox1);
    rect->Parent = VertScrollBox1;
    rect->OnClick = RectLogicClick;
    rect->Width = 100;
    rect->Height = 50;
    rect->Position->X = 10;
    rect->Position->Y = 20 + i*50;
    rects[i] = rect;
  }
}
```

in destructor

```
__fastcall TForm1::~TForm1()
{
  for(int i=0; i<20; ++i)
  {
    rects[i]->Parent = nullptr; 
    delete rects[i];
  }
}
```

And in RectLogicClick

```
void __fastcall TForm1::RectLogicClick(TObject *Sender)
{
  ShowMessage("Rect Clicked");
}
```

if you run this in an Android device and you scroll and stop over any Rectangle it's **OnClick** event is fired.

Is any way of lock the event **onClick** when the Scroll is scrolling ?

this project is orient to an mobile devices, using firemonkey(C++) framework and Rad Studio 10.2.1 tokyo

Comment: Is there something in `Sender` you can check to see if it is a click, move, or release of a button?

Comment: Not, it is just a pointer to object that is clicked, in this case some **TRectangle**